# how do I modify org.eclipse.ui.workbench plugin

Tags: swt, rcp, jface, workbench

I want my application shaped changed by modifying org.eclipse.ui.workbench plugin.
but the problem is even though I import it with source , it is not operated.

How do I solve this out?

Comment: can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: Care to upvote/accept an answer or tell us more about what kind of explanations you want?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like importing a plugin from source leaves the *.properties files behind. They are required, however; and must be copied manually in order for the plugin to be functional.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that :-)

Two reasons:

(1) as soon as you switch to a newer version of Eclipse, your code won't work. You have to merge all the changes that had gone into workbench plugin

(2) By modifying the code and not submitting the changes back, you are violating EPL. (I'm not a lawyer, so check with a real lawyer for more details)